# Animated Text Jquery is failing on IE 8 and IE 9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate

I am facing strange problem on IE 8 where Animated Text is not working on IE 8 and IE 9. Here is the following example of the site where this problem is arising.

[Click Here to see the SIte](http://www.indiacarbonltd.com/home.html)

I have tested it on Mozila Firefox, Google Chrome, Apple Safari, Opera and IE 10, IE 11 anddidn't find anything but on IE 8 and IE 9 I found a javascript is being crashed. Neighter I could solve the problem of the jquery nor I found the same jquery like this animated text.

Here is the code example of the page.

**HTML**

```
<table width="896" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>
    <td height="3" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="images/logo.png" width="220" height="115" /></td>
        <td valign="bottom">
        <ul id="dropdown">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="profile.html">Company Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="founders.html">Founders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="board.html">Board of Directors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="investors.html">investors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="quaterly.html">Quaterly Result </a></li>
                        <li><a href="share.html">Distribution of Shareholding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="corporate.html">Corporate Governance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="report.html">Annual Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="code.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
                  </ul>
              <li><a href="#">Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="calcined.html">Calcined Petroleum Coke</a></li>
                        <li><a href="electrode.html">Electrode Carbon Paste</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tamping.html">Tamping Paste</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </li>
                <li><a href="social.html">Social Responsibility</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="contactinf.html">Contact Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="queries.html">Queries</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </ul>       </td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="4" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <div>
        <div class="banner rounded-btm">        
            <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="" /></li>     
        </div>
        <div id="text-scroll" class="tlt">India's Leading Producer of Calcinated Petroleum Coke</div>
    </div>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="headerbelow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome to India Carbon Limited<br />
    <br /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="648" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="84%" class="bodytxt"><p><strong>INDIA CARBON LIMITED (ICL)</strong>, India’s leading producer of Calcined Petroleum Coke, provides the right blend of people & products to serve the needs of the Aluminum, Steel, & other Carbon consuming industries.

</p>
          <p><strong>Calcined Petroleum Coke (CPC)</strong> is used extensively as Anode in Alumina Smelters, as Soderberg's Electrode for Ferroalloy Industries, and in the manufacturing of Graphite/ Graphite Electrodes, and Thermal Paste for Ferro Alloys & allied industries in Submerged Arc Furnaces.            </p>
          <p><strong>CPC</strong> is also used in various Steel Industries for - Melting of Steel , Recurburisation and for making Special Steels & Alloys. </p>
          </td>
        <td width="11%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    </td>
    <td width="235" rowspan="3" valign="top" class="rightmenu">
    <ul id="example" class="tlt">
        <li>Pride</li>
        <li>Passion</li>
        <li>Belief</li>
        <li>Creativity</li>
        <li>Integrity</li>
        <li>Team Work</li>
        <li>Ownership</li>
        <li>Winning</li>
    </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div align="center" class="rightheader"><a href="core.html" target="_blank" class="pageheader style1">Click Here</a> </div></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="footer"><div align="center">Copyright &copy; 2012 India Carbon Ltd | All rights reserved<br />
    developed &amp; maintained by RightClik</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/juizDropDownMenu-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.js"></script>
<script src="js/animateText.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.tlt').textillate({   
      loop: true,   
      minDisplayTime: 2000,   
      initialDelay: 2,   
      autoStart: true,    
      inEffects: ['flipInX'],    
      outEffects: [ 'fadeOut' ],    
      in: {     
        effect: 'flipInX',      
        delayScale: 1.5,        
        delay: 50,  
        sync: false,        
        shuffle: false
      },
      out: {
        effect: 'fadeOut',
        delayScale: 1.5,
        delay: 50,
        sync: false,
        shuffle: false,
      }
    });

    $('#example').textillate({   
      loop: true,   
      minDisplayTime: 3000,   
      initialDelay: 1,   
      autoStart: true,    
      inEffects: ['fadeInLeft'],     
      outEffects: [ 'rollOut' ],    
      in: {     
        effect: 'fadeInLeft',       
        delayScale: 1.5,        
        delay: 50,  
        sync: false,        
        shuffle: false
      },
      out: {
        effect: 'rollOut',
        delayScale: 1.5,
        delay: 50,
        sync: false,
        shuffle: false,
      }
    });


    $(".banner").responsiveSlides({speed: 2500});

    $("#dropdown").juizDropDownMenu({
                'showEffect' : 'fade',
                'hideEffect' : 'slide'
    });

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textObjects = [
        {
            offset: 0,
            duration: 3000,
            animation: 'leftToRight',
            positions: {
            start: {               
                'font-size': '20px',
                'font-weight': 600,
                color: '#000',

                }
            }
        },
        {
            offset: 2000,
            duration: 3000,
            animation: 'explode',
            positions: {
            start: {               
                'font-size': '20px',              
                color: '#000',

                }
            }

        },
        {
            offset: 3500,
            duration: 3000,
            animation: 'rightToLeft',
            positions: {
            start: {
                top:'25px',
                left:'-20px',
                'font-size': '30px',
                'font-weight': 600,
                color: '#000',

                }
            }
        }

    ],
    options = {
        repeat: true
    },
    animations = {
        topToBottom: {
            positions: {
                start: {
                    bottom: '50%',
                    left: '0%',
                },
                1:  {
                    bottom: '60%'
                }
            }
        }
    };
    $("#example").animateText(textObjects, options, animations);
</script>
```

I am getting error in JS `<script src="js/jquery.textillate.js"></script>` it is showing error on IE 8 and collapsing all other jquery with itself so the whole site is getting messed up with the design and everything else.I am very much confused about it and can not figure what to do. Can anyoneone guide me regarding this. Or help me to find the same Jquery which support IE 8 and IE 9 also including all other browser.

I am sorry I was unable to post the code and show live demo on JSFiddle as this page so I gave the full URL of the site which is shown above.